# Почему цикл работает бесконечно

Tags: java

Есть задача:

> Из ряда натуральных чисел от 1 до 2009 вычеркнули все нечётные числа. Из оставшихся вычеркнули числа, стоявшие на нечётных местах. Эту процедуру повторяли до тех пор, пока не осталось только одно число. Найдите последнее оставшееся число.

Пытаюсь делать так:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2009; i++) {
            list.add(i + 1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { //не увеличивает счетчик
            if (list.get(i) % 2 != 0)
                list.remove(i);
            else
                break; //при замене на i++ счетчик скачет на +2
        }
        while (list.size() > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (i % 2 != 0) {
                    list.remove(i);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Нужно найти последнее оставшееся число. Однако третий цикл бесконечный (вернее, `i` не увеличивается). Почему?

Comment: Нельзя удалять из списка в цикле. Нельзя.... теряется индекс..... исключением может быть разве что итерирование с конца в начало, но не наоборот. Банально включите отладчик и посмотрите что происходит со списком на каждой итерации.... у вас же есть отладчик, правда?

Comment: так мне и нужно удалять в цикле...Я так предположил,что с удалением индекса и одновременном увеличении i курсор как раз и будет вставать на нечетные индекс и сразу его удалять

Comment: Смотрел в отладчике- i просто не увеличивается и собственно ничего не происходит,дальше не идет цикл

Comment: Во втором цикле при удалении индекса все идет нормально,как надо...Но там именно ищу нечетные значения и удаляю индес.Дальше надо уже не по значениям,а именно по нечетным индексам скакать и удалять их пока не останется последний

Comment: если вместо break ставлю i++,то на следующей итерации начинает работать увеличение i в условии(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) и получается не +1, а +2 и из-за этого я перескакиваю все нечетные и опять не идет цикл

Comment: `так мне и нужно удалять в цикле..` - ты прочитал мой комментарий внимательно? ............`Смотрел в отладчике- i` - ты смотри не на счётчик (точнее не только на него), а на коллекцию, что происходит с ней......

Comment: @Regent извиняюсь! Даны натуральные числа от 1 до 2009 в списке.Сперва надо убрать все нечетные числа, затем уже убрать все числа по нечетным индексам(и так пока не останется последнее число-оно то и нужно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский коллекция не уменьшается,т.к. счетчик не увеличивается и цикл стоит на 0 индексе

Comment: @Regent надо найти последнее оставшееся число.Запустите мой код если не сложно-счетчик не хочет увеличиваться!

Comment: @Regent написал условие

Comment: `последнее оставшееся число` - последнее число берется вот так: `list.get(list.size() - 1);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну нет)))Надо именно убирать нечетные индексы,пока не останется 1(list,size() == 1) вот число под этим индексом и нужно!

Comment: @trufan ну в итоге вы все равно попадете на элемент, находящийся либо в конце, либо предпоследний (в зависимости от размера списка), разве нет?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет))при каждой итерации числа сдвикаютя на одну ячейку влево

Comment: Из ряда натуральных чисел от 1 до 2009 вычеркнули все нечётные числа. Из оставшихся вычеркнули числа, стоявшие на нечётных местах. Эту процедуру повторяли до тех пор, пока не осталось только одно число. Найдите последнее оставшееся число. 
Точное условие задачи!

Comment: Возможно на нулевом индексе(он то по идее является четным и не сдвигается) окажется то число(2),но нужно именно в задаче найти его

Comment: при изменении условия на начальный индекс i=1 цикл работает,и получается ответ 2 на нулевом индексе,но в задаче мы его просто пропустили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стал читать комменты, может, там и есть верное решение, но скажу, что проблема у Вас здесь:

```
if (i % 2 != 0) {
    list.remove(i);
}
    else
        break;
```

В начале цикла, когда ещё i = 0, Вы получаете break и выходите на while, при этом, так как list.size() остался прежним, т.е. > 0, всё повторяется.

Comment: ,да проблема в этом цикле

Comment: спасибо!Очень помог!

Answer (score 1):

Цикл для удаления из списка элементов, стоящих на четных индексах (в массивах и списках индексы идут с нуля, а не с единицы как в рядах), должен выглядеть так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    list.remove(i);
}
```

В этом случае и элементы нужные удалятся, и связка `while`-`for` не будет работать бесконечно.

Альтернативный вариант с итератором, возможно, выглядит интуитивно понятнее:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{
    it.next();
    it.remove();
    if (it.hasNext())
    {
        it.next();
    }
}
```

---

Удаление из списка нечётных чисел также можно сделать с помощью итератора, чтобы не заморачиваться с индексами после удаления элемента:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{
    if (it.next() % 2 == 1)
    {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

---

Учитывая что удаление элементов происходит с фиксированных индексов, можно обойтись без удаления элементов, просчитав вместо этого индекс элемента, который в итоге останется:

```
if (!list.isEmpty())
{
    int size = 1;
    while (size <= list.size())
    {
        size <<= 1;
    }
    System.out.println(list.get(size / 2 - 1));
}
```

Для списка из, например, миллиона чисел этот вариант будет работать намного быстрее.

---

Код создания списка и фильтрации чисел можно сократить, используя Java 8:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, 2010).boxed()
        .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: спасибо, но до Java 8 мне рановато))Пока еще учу основы))